# Flag for just create an empty file if not exists?

Tags: php, file, fopen

**Which flag should i use for create a file if not exists?** Please not that i'll close the point right after `fopen()` because the "hard part" (decoding the encrypted content) is carried by `load()` function (decoding logic is not shown):

```
Class MyClass
{
   protected $filename, $data;

   public function __construct($filename)
   {
       $this->filename = $filename;

       // Create if not exists
       if(!file_exists($this->filename))
       {
          $fp = fopen($this->filename, '');
          fclose($fp);
       }

       $this->load();
   }

   public function load()
   {
      $data = file_get_contents($this->filename);
      $this->data = $data === false ? array() : $data;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wb` is about all you'd need. Open a file for writing, truncate any file which already exists, set the file pointer to the start of this new file, and enable binary mode (which prevents PHP from translating line-ending characters on certain platforms like Windows).

Answer (score 0):

`'a+'`, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) manual. Ensure that permissions for the dir is ok.